# Why does casting from String[] to Object only work with a reference?

Tags: java, casting

My question boils down to:
Why does

```
Object test = {"2"};
```

not work while

```
 String[] test = {"2"};
 Object bla = test;
```

does?

Comment: because `{"2"}` is identified as array of string literals. `Object test = new Object[]{"2"};` works as well because you tell the compiler that you have an `Object array`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Would you mind putting that as an answer?

Comment: You are using [**array initializer**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6)  syntax.

Comment: `{"2"}` isn't really "identified as an array of string literals". The problem isn't that it's a string array rather than an object array - it's that this is *array initializer* syntax, which is only valid when initializing an array variable.

Comment: @PM77-1 that you for introducing the syntax however after a short read of the specs I didnt see anything forbidding me to immediatly cast it. But that might be my english not being good enough.

Comment: I believe that is the bold part:  **Each variable initializer must be assignment-compatible (§5.2) with the array's component type, or a compile-time error occurs.**

Comment: @JonSkeet so it boils down to if you want to use array initializer syntax you need to explicitly create an array?

Comment: @Vringar: Yes. Note that `String[] test = { "2" };` and `String[] test = new String[] { "2" };` will do *exactly* the same thing - it only avoids you needing to write the `new String[]` part. You can write `Object bla = new String[] { "2" };` if you want.

Comment: @PM77-1 yeah but a cast from String[] to Object is _from my understanding_ a [a widening reference conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5) which is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the compiler thinks that {"2"} it is an array but if you declare directly with an object you have to specify it is gonna be an array too.